# UnicodeEncodeError on Pycharm but not on the console

Tags: python, unicode, pycharm

Why does running the statement `u'ç' + 'a'` through PyCharm result in this exception:

`UnicodeEncodeError 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe7'`

but running it through an interactive console works as expected?

```
>>> u'ç' + 'a'
u'\xe7a'
```

I'm using the same virtual environment in both contexts.

Comment: Check the result of `sys.getdefaultencoding()` on both of them. Just a guess.

Comment: Both return 'ascii'.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "running [...] through PyCharm"? Do you mean that you have a file containing this statement or do you run it in the PyCharm console?

Comment: I mean that I have a file having this statement.